# TypeError: _this.props.menuData is not a function in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to pass a object from child component on submit, but i am
getting the above error

Below is the code in child and parent component

```
overideChange = (e) => {
      let menuObj = {
            currency: e.target.currency.value
      }
      this.props.menuData(menuObj);             
}

<OlmiGridNavMenu  menuData={this.menuData} />

menuData(data) {
      console.log('data--->', data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before sending **menuData** function as props from parent component, bind **this** to that props.

```
<OlmiGridNavMenu  menuData={this.menuData.bind(this)} />
```

or you can bind this to **menuData** in the class constructor.

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.menuData = this.menuData.bind(this);
    }

    menuData(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }

   render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <OlmiGridNavMenu  menuData={this.menuData} />
            </div>
        );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind `this`

```
<OlmiGridNavMenu  menuData={this.menuData.bind(this)} />
```